# XLOOKUP match emails

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write an excel `XLOOKUP` query.

Where I have 2 table -

**Table 1**

```
Email           Found/Not Found
user1@ss.se
user2@ss.se    
user3@ss.se
user4@ss.se
```

**Table 2**

```
Email
user2@ss.se    
user3@ss.se
```

In `table 1` I want to find if any of the `emails` can be found in `table 2`. If the `emails` is found the result should be `found` else `not found`

**Expected result**

```
Email          Found/Not Found
user1@ss.se   Not Found
user2@ss.se    Found
user3@ss.se   Found
user4@ss.se   Not Found
```

I have tried this query but it is giving me an error message

```
=XLOOKUP(A2;table2!A2:A5;"Found";"";0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Match:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,table2!$A$2:$A$5,0)),"Found","Not Found")
```

[image]

If you really want to use XLOOKUP, we need to do some trickery.

```
=LET(lkp,table2!$A$2:$A$5,XLOOKUP(A2,lkp,INDEX({"found"},SEQUENCE(ROWS(lkp),,1,0)),"not found",0))
```

[image]

Comment: you are awesome

Answer (score 1):

A different approach using XLOOKUP:

```
=XLOOKUP(A3,$E$2:$E$5,IF(ISTEXT($E$2:$E$5),"Found"),"Not Found")
```

[image]